# Logging the time for each test (and/or testSuite) with scala test

Tags: scala, scalatest, specs2

I'm using scala test for my tests, and some time ago the builds started to fail sometimes because some (new, probably) test takes more than the limit allowed by the CI.

At first sight no test should take more than the timeout (10 minutes btw), and by the CI output it not easy to see which test is taking so much time (or how much time every test takes)

I can put simple println-based statements to print the current hour at the beginning/end of each test, but I was wondering if scala test provides some builtin feature for that?

If no, does any other scala test framework/library does?

> EDIT: tried to wrap the test

I prefere some native method from the lib itself. I was trying to wrap a specs2 test in a method that would get the description and log the times, but I'm having difficulties in running the test in the moment I want to. I did something Like this:

```
class SomeSpec {
    private def withTimeLog(x: Fragment) = {
        println(s"Starting test: ${x.description}(${DateTime.now()})")

        //what now?
        x.executionResult

        println(s"End of test: ${x.description}(${DateTime.now()})")
      }

      withTimeLog("Feature" should {
        "stuff" in {
          println(s"test: ${DateTime.now()}")
          None.isEmpty must beTrue
        }
      })
}
```

and the result:

```
Starting test: End(2016-07-28T18:11:53.101+01:00)
End of test: End(2016-07-28T18:11:53.191+01:00)
[info] FeatureSpecV2
[info]
test running at 2016-07-28T18:11:54.037+01:00
[info] A test should
[info]   + stuff
```

meaning, test was executed in the end, and not between the 2 print statements. Maybe Fragment.execution result doesn't run the test. Tried with several others. Any idea which method should I be using?

Comment: Check the test report in target.

Comment: What are you using as CI platform? Probably Jenkins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display execution times in specs2 by passing the [`showtimes`](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.8.4/org.specs2.guide.ArgumentsReference.html#reporting) option on the command line

```
sbt>testOnly *MySpec -- showtimes
```

Also if you use future matchers you can adjust a "time factor" with the [`timeFactor`](https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.8.4/org.specs2.guide.ArgumentsReference.html#execution) command line option.

Comment: having problems trying to use your solution...is the flag available only since some specific version? `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument unrecognized by ScalaTest's Runner: showtimes`

Comment: That's because ScalaTest is also one of the testing frameworks of sbt. And it parses all arguments in sbt, even the ones from specs2. You can get around this by typing: `sbt> set testFrameworks := Seq(TestFrameworks.Specs2)`.